# Is it okay to put enums inside a class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this class, I want the enums to be found at one location because I had experienced enums are declared on the top of a class definition where it going to be used which sometimes I was having a hard time to look where did this enum was declared.

Is it okay like this? But my problem is that this can be instantiated or inheritable which is not necessary and must be avoided.

```
 public class Enumerations
{
    public enum ComputerTypes
    {
        Laptop,
        Desktop
    }

    public enum Brands
    {
        APPLE,
        DELL
    }

    public enum Processors
    {
        I3,
        I5,
        I7
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just put them in the same file under the same namespace?

Comment: `and must be avoided.` Why?

Comment: "Is it okay" is allmost allways opinion-based. One sais "yes", another one "no". There´s absolutely no objective way to determine a "right" or "whrong" answer here.

Comment: Sharing files between non-nested classes is gross.

Comment: You can make your `Enumerations` class static. This will not allow inheritance or instantiation

Comment: F12, for all your definition lookup needs. Lacking support in your editor/IDE is not a compelling reason to put things in classes, and it doesn't even actually solve the problem once and for all -- this works in one project, what if there's more than one? How about multiple assemblies? How many `Enumerations` classes would you end up with, and how much "easier" would it be to find them (and figure out what enumeration goes where)?

Comment: @mjwills Because I think it is not good to instantiate or inherit from a class who only contains enums. When I could just call it like this Enumerations.ComputerTypes.Laptop.

Comment: I would argue that having a big class with all enumerations in clearly violates v1 of the Single Responsibility Principle, where Uncle Bob stated "A module should have one, and only one reason to change".  But later that has been redefined as "A module should be responsible to one, and only one, actor." where a [module](http://principles-wiki.net/glossary:module) becomes the most overloaded term in computing!

Comment: When you think - for whatever reason that we still don´t know - inherting a class containing any nested class, enum or struct, is bad, then make that class `sealed`. If your class shouldn´t be instantiable, make it `static`. I feel you´re misusing the prinicple of a `class` to group common data-structures together. Have you thought about just using a common namespace `ComputerTypes` instead of a `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay like this?

This is and always be personal opinion or company standard and there is no concrete answer. That said:

You can remove class identificator and put them under same namespace:

```
namespace Enums
{
    public enum ComputerTypes
    {
        Laptop,
        Desktop
    }

    public enum Brands
    {
        APPLE,
        DELL
    }

    public enum Processors
    {
        I3,
        I5,
        I7
    }
}
```

Comment: glad you pointed out this is opinion because this and having files that don't match the class name drives and directories that don't match the namespace/project/solution structure drives me crazy.